# How to sort list of MAC addresses in java?

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have a list of MAC addresses as string. Need to sort them (or) should check if the array of MAC addresses are in sorted manner. How to achieve this

**Sample MAC addresses:**

50:07:0c:00:00:67:98

51:06:0d:00:00:67:98

50:06:0f:00:00:67:98

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have some special requirement that is not stated, you can just put them in a `List` and then call `Collections.sort(list)`.